# Combining select queries to combine data from two tables

Tags: sql

I'm working on an assignment and am stuck on something and I hope someone can assist.

I have two tables. I need to perform a count on pp_inventory_id in the pp_Orders and then pull the associated names, addresses, ect. from a second table nc_Customer. The end result is supposed to produce the names and addresses of customers who have purchased an item that has sold three or more of said item.

I can get each query to work individually but am supposed to create a single query. I suspect UNION is the way to go but I just can't figure out how to get the two to work together as a single query. Any suggestions would be most appreciated.

The first query selects, counts and produces the correct ID#:

```
(
 SELECT pp_inventory_id, COUNT(*) AS "Number of Orders" 
 FROM pp_Order
 GROUP BY pp_inventory_id
 HAVING COUNT(pp_Order.pp_inventory_id) >=3
)
```

The second query selects correct customer info of customers who have purchased said item IDs:

```
SELECT 
    nc_first_name, 
    nc_last_name,
    nc_street_address, 
    nc_state_plus_zipcode, 
    pp_Order.pp_inventory_id 
FROM nc_Customer
    JOIN pp_Order on pp_Order.pp_customer_id = nc_customer_id
GROUP BY nc_first_name, nc_last_name, nc_street_address,
    nc_state_plus_zipcode, pp_Order.pp_inventory_id
```

Comment: Could you use http://sqlfiddle.com/ and add data. This would work best when asking for assistance on here.

Also, did you try to do a nested query? I would fetch the data necessary for the final report for the main query, then use a sub query for the IN clause on the customer IDs. The nested query is where you would have the having clause as this is what will return the resultset of valid customer IDs

Comment: you need to use an inner join.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you need the corresponding customer information associated with the query which already works for you (orders of 3 or more)?  If so, you can move that query in an `exists` clause:

```
select * 
from nc_customer c 
where exists (
    select 1 
    from pp_order o 
    where o.pp_customer_id = c.nc_customer_id 
    group by o.pp_inventory_id 
    having count(o.pp_inventory_id) >= 3
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can merge your query by using join between them

```
select T1.*,T2.* from
(
 SELECT pp_inventory_id, COUNT(*) AS "Number of Orders" 
 FROM pp_Order
 GROUP BY pp_inventory_id
 HAVING COUNT(pp_Order.pp_inventory_id) >=3
) as T1
inner join 
(SELECT 
    nc_first_name, 
    nc_last_name,
    nc_street_address, 
    nc_state_plus_zipcode, 
    pp_Order.pp_inventory_id 
FROM nc_Customer
    JOIN pp_Order on pp_Order.pp_customer_id = nc_customer_id
GROUP BY nc_first_name, nc_last_name, nc_street_address, nc_state_plus_zipcode, pp_Order.pp_inventory_id
) as T2 on T1.pp_inventory_id=T2.pp_inventory_id
```